# What does "| \" mean?

Tags: c

In WINUSER.H, it defines WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW like this:

```
#define WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW (WS_OVERLAPPED     | \
                             WS_CAPTION        | \
                             WS_SYSMENU        | \
                             WS_THICKFRAME     | \
                             WS_MINIMIZEBOX    | \
                             WS_MAXIMIZEBOX)
```

What I don't understand is, rather than `operator |`, what does `| \` do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\` as the LAST character of a line means "this line is not finished". It disappears from the preprocessed output.

Those lines are equivalent to:

```
#define WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW (WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | ...
```

just a bit more readable.

Answer (score 6):

The pipe is a bitwise OR, and the backslash signals that the definition continues on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

The pipe symbol "|" bitwise or's these constants, the backslash just escapes the following line-wrap.

Answer (score 1):

| is bitwise OR

\ at the end of a line is continuation in next line of something you'd otherwise write in a single line - It merges two physical lines to a logical line.

The below line is equivalent.

```
#define WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW (WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX)
```

Answer (score 1):

The \ is simply a line continuation character; it means the next physical line is part of the same logical line.  It's just for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Two separate things. The `|` is the bitwise OR operator, and the `\` is telling the preprocessor to add the stuff on the *next* line to *this* line. This is the same as

```
#define WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW (WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The \ is used at the end of the line so the definition can extend to more than one line.